# stop printf printing twice running check framework in C?

Tags: c, printf, buffer, check-framework

1. Probably a deep explanation of how printing in general in c and c threads happen would solve the issue
2. There aren't loops and scanf used at any point
3. Because my code uses check framework I would assume there is some forking going on.
4. Most likely it is something to do with the buffer so I am using fflush(stdout), In case it is because of something inside the framework, I'd appreciate somebody who knows the framework will explain what happens.
5. check framework page check.sourceforge.net
6. Git link if this may help somehow https://github.com/batousik/Practical-C2
7. Link to build/test log, at line 438 printing starts https://travis-ci.org/batousik/Practical-C2/builds/53513707

Code sample

```
START_TEST(test_START_EMPTY_TREE_TREEBASE_PRINT_FREETREE_TEST) {
    printf("_________START_EMPTY_TREE/TREEBASE_PRINT/FREETREE_TEST__________\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    int *ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
        memcpy(ptr, (int_arr_ptr + i), sizeof(int));
        insert(ptr_tree_base_int_1, ptr);
    }
    // should print tree
    printf("!!!Next lines has to be tree printed out\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    ck_assert_int_eq(printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), true);
    printf("_____________________\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    // No output
    ck_assert_int_eq(freeTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), true);
    // should print cannot free empty tree
    printf("!!!Next line has to be:\"cannot free empty tree\"\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    ck_assert_int_eq(freeTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), true);

    // should print cannot print empty tree
    printf("!!!Next line has to be:\"cannot print empty tree\"\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    ck_assert_int_eq(printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), false);
    printf("_____________________\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    ptr_tree_base_int_1 = NULL;
    free(ptr_tree_base_int_1);

    // should print cannot free empty tree base
    printf("!!!Next line has to be:\"cannot free empty tree base\"\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    ck_assert_int_eq(freeTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), true);

    // should print cannot print empty tree base
    printf("!!!Next line has to be:\"cannot print empty tree base\"\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    ck_assert_int_eq(printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), false);
    printf("_____________________\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    free(int_arr_ptr);
    int_arr_ptr = NULL;
    printf("freeing the array...\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("________END_____________\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    ck_assert_int_eq(ptr_tree_base_int_1->size, 0);
} END_TEST
```

PrintTree function

```
bool printTree(TreeBase *tree){
void *previous = NULL;
int cnt_tasks = 0;
if (!tree) {
    printf("PRINT: Cannot print empty tree base\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return false;
}
/* set current to root of binary tree */
TreeNode *current_node = tree->base;
if (!(tree->base)) {
    printf("PRINT: Cannot print empty tree\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return false;
}
StackNode *stack = NULL;
while (true) {
    if(current_node) {
        push(&stack, current_node);
        current_node = current_node->left;
    } else {
        if (stack) {
            current_node = pop(&stack);
            if (cnt_tasks > 1) {
                if (tree->comp(previous, current_node->value) != -1) {
                    printf("PRINTTREE: Invalid BST\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    assert(NULL);
                }
            }
            previous = current_node->value;
            tree->print(current_node->value);
            cnt_tasks++;
            current_node = current_node->right;
        } else {
            return (cnt_tasks == tree->size);
        }
    }
}
```

}

tree->print function

```
void print_ints(void *p){
   printf("%d\n", *(int*)p);
   fflush(stdout);
}
```

Sample output

```
    FREETREE: Cant free empty tree
    !!!Next line has to be:"cannot free empty tree"
    FREETREE: Cant free empty tree
    FREETREE: Cant free empty tree
    !!!Next line has to be:"cannot print empty tree"
    PRINT: Cannot print empty tree
    PRINT: Cannot print empty tree
    _____________________
```

**That is a lot of code, Main point is after !!! there should be one line but two printed**

```
    printf("PRINT: Cannot print empty tree\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return false;
```

^^ This line prints twice

For comments: what is "Macros"? and this is from the API

```
#define     ck_assert_int_eq(X, Y)   _ck_assert_int(X, ==, Y)
```

Comment: I assume that the assert functions are not actually "functions" but preprocessor macros, and depending on the macros the arguments can be evaluated multiple times which in the case of your function calls will mean that the functions are called multiple times. I recommend you run the code through the preprocessor only, and look what the code looks like after preprocessing.

Comment: If `ck_assert_int_eq` is a macro (and it seem to be according to [this site](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_4.html)), then there's a chance the argument is evaluated more than one. Try moving the argument outside the macro (e.g. with `int rc = printTree...; ck_assert_int_eq(rc, ...`)

Comment: @SLeuthEye Did that, **line 438**, [link](https://travis-ci.org/batousik/Practical-C2/builds/53514717). Apart from Segmentation fault _it works!! :)_ can you please explain why it works?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Please exaplin why :)

Comment: The classical example is a macro to get the maximum of two values, like `#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))`. If invoked like `int x = 2, y = 1, m = MAX(x, y);` then the expression `x` will be evaluated *twice*, while the expression `y` will be evaluated once. If the expression `x` instead of being a simple integer variable was a function call that called `printf` that function would be called twice and the `printf` would be done twice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ck_assert_int_eq` [macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion) introduced in version 0.9.6 of the [Check unit testing framework](http://check.sourceforge.net/) was defined as:

```
#define _ck_assert_int(X, O, Y) ck_assert_msg((X) O (Y), \
  "Assertion '"#X#O#Y"' failed: "#X"==%d, "#Y"==%d", X, Y) 
#define ck_assert_int_eq(X, Y) _ck_assert_int(X, ==, Y)
```

As can be seen, the arguments appear twice in the macro definition: one time for the actual equality check (the `(X) O (Y)` part), and another as the last arguments to `ck_assert_msg(..., X, Y)` for the purpose of logging a message in case of failure. Looking at a specific part of your code:

```
// should print cannot print empty tree
printf("!!!Next line has to be:\"cannot print empty tree\"\n");
fflush(stdout);
ck_assert_int_eq(printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), false);
```

the C-preprocessor would correspondingly expand the macro to code equivalent to:

```
// should print cannot free empty tree
printf("!!!Next line has to be:\"cannot free empty tree\"\n");
fflush(stdout);
ck_assert_msg((printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1)) == (false), 
  "Assertion '"#X#O#Y"' failed: "#X"==%d, "#Y"==%d", 
  printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1), false);
```

The `printTree` function is thus called twice with all the associated side effects, including printing the line `"PRINT: Cannot print empty tree"` twice.
One way to protect yourself against this kind of error is to make sure arguments to macros have no possible side effects. This can be accomplished in your case, by moving the call to `printTree` outside the macro:

```
bool printTreeResult;
printTreeResult = printTree(ptr_tree_base_int_1);
ck_assert_int_eq(printTreeResult, false);
```

Note that since this kind of macro is generally error prone (as you've just experienced), the definition of the `ck_assert_int_eq` was improved in version 0.9.9 to:

```
#define _ck_assert_int(X, OP, Y) do { \
  int _ck_x = (X); \
  int _ck_y = (Y); \
  ck_assert_msg(_ck_x OP _ck_y, \
    "Assertion '"#X#OP#Y"' failed: "#X"==%d, "#Y"==%d", _ck_x, _ck_y); \
} while (0)
#define ck_assert_int_eq(X, Y) _ck_assert_int(X, ==, Y)
```

Correspondingly, another way to fix the problem with duplicated output lines would be to upgrade your installation of the Check unit testing framework to a more recent version (i.e. at least 0.9.9), if that's an option.